# How to convert into java mongodb using mongotemplate or mongo repository(custom repository)

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

```
db.profileInterest.aggregate([
   { $project: { _id: 1, fromProfile: 1, toProfile: 1, contactNoViewed:1, shortListed: 1, count: {$size: '$interestStatus'}, threeFavorites: { $slice: [ "$interestStatus", -1 ] }} },
   {$match: {"threeFavorites.id": {$ne: 100}}}
]).pretty();
```

Answer (score 1):

save aggregation output in `List<DBObject>` as below :

```
AggregationOutput aggregationOutput = mongoTemplate
        .getCollection("collection_name")
        .aggregate(aggregationList);

List<DBObject> dbObjects = (List<DBObject>) aggregationOutput.results();
```

convert `List<DBObject>` in java type as below :

```
for(DBObject dbObject : dbObjects) {
    mongoTemplate.getConverter().read(klass, dbObject);
}
```